# SaltStack: Which firewall rule for outgoing traffic on minions?

Tags: firewall, saltstack

On a network where all OUTPUT ports are closed by default on minion servers, and only required ports are opened, which ports do I have to open on the minion servers for the communication between the Salt master and Salt minions?

This is on Debian GNU/Linux 8.5 (jessie), with Salt master and minions version 2016.3.3 (Boron)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Salt minions connect to the master using TCP ports 4505 and 4506.

On firewalled minions one would need the equivalent of:

```
iptables -I OUTPUT -d <master IP/netblock> -p tcp -m multiport --dports 4505,4506 -j ACCEPT
```

On a firewalled Salt master one would need the equivalent of:

```
iptables -I INPUT -s <minion IP/netblock> -p tcp -m multiport --dports 4505,4506 -j ACCEPT
```

Comment: Yeah, that's right, but ..."All OUTPUT ports are closed on minion servers." I want to open the required ports on the minions to allow outgoing traffic to the master server ;)

Comment: iptables -I OUTPUT -d 0.0.0.0/0 -p tcp -m multiport --dports 4505,4506 -j ACCEPT

Comment: replace 0.0.0.0/0 with the master(s) ip(s)